# Returning multiple variables from within method in powershell class

Tags: powershell, class, variables, return

I am creating a class in powershell to manage authorization to an api. Now if for some reason the connection fails, i want to return a message and a return code.

I have a constructor, this one is calling a static method (thus i am not able to use $this...). Found some example (not used in a class though) explaining i could create a hashtable to return from my method, but for some reason this does not work.

```
Class ApiAuth
{
    [string] $APIUser
    hidden [string] $ApiPassword
    [string] $ApiUrl
    [string] $authorization
    hidden [string] $bodyParams
    [int] $ReturnCode

    ApiAuth([string] $APIUser, [string] $ApiPassword, [string] $ApiUrl)
    {

        Write-Host "HIER1" -ForegroundColor Yellow

        $this.APIUser     = $APIUser
        $this.ApiPassword = $ApiPassword
        $this.ApiUrl      = ($ApiUrl, "Login") -join  "/"
        $this.bodyParams = @{"UserName"= $this.APIUser; "Password" = $this.ApiPassword} | ConvertTo-Json        
        $t1 = [ApiAuth]::Connect($this.ApiUrl, $this.bodyParams)


        Write-Host $t1.Length -ForegroundColor Cyan


        Write-Host $t1.ToString() -ForegroundColor RED
        Write-Host $t1['auth'] -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host $t1.code -ForegroundColor GREEN
        #Write-Host $temp[1] -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }


    Reconnect()
    {
        $this.authorization = [ApiAuth]::Connect($this.ApiUrl, $this.bodyParams)
    }

    static [String] Connect([string] $ApiUrl, [string] $bodyParams)
    {
        try {
            $rest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ApiUrl -Method POST -Body $bodyParams -ContentType 'application/json'
            #
            #$this.ReturnCode = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
            $ret = @{}
            $ret.auth = $rest.Headers.Authorization
            $ret.code = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode

            return $ret

            #Return $rest.Headers.Authorization
            #Return $rest.Headers.Authorization, [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
        }       
        catch [System.Net.WebException] {
            Write-Host "HIER2" -ForegroundColor RED
            Write-Host $_.Exception -ForegroundColor RED
            #$this.ReturnCode = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode

            if([int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode -eq 401) {


            }

            return $false
        }
         catch {
            Write-Host "HIER3" -ForegroundColor RED
            #$this.ReturnCode = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
            return $false
        }

    }

}
```

Now i am looking for a way to return multiple values to act on this accordingly. Or maybe i can call "Connect()" without making it static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return object

```
$local:o = New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{ 
    'ReasonText' = $reasonText;
    'ReasonCode' = $reasonCode;
}
return $local:o
```

**UPDATE: Better way with PSCustomObject**

```
return [PSCustomObject]@{ 
    'ReasonText' = $reasonText;
    'ReasonCode' = $reasonCode;
    }
```

---

Alternative: Use `[ref]` inputs:

```
function xxx {
    Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ref]$ReasonTextOut = $Null
    )
    if ($ReasonTextOut -eq $null) {
        $ReasonTextOut = New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Propery @{Value = ''}
    }
    ...
    $ReasonTextOut.Value = $reasonText
    return $reasonCode
}

$Output = '';
$code = xxx -ReasonTextOut ([ref]$Output)
Write-Host "Code: $($code); Output: $($Output)".
```

---

Personally I think that in most cases, first way is better